# android:text assign string resource & text

Tags: android

I would like to assign a string resource and some additional text to a textview.
Is there a way to do this, without adding a second textview?

Something like this:

```
android:text="@string/DESCRIPTION"+": "
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense, why don't you just define your description as resource, too? If you want to set it programmatically, it's no problem: `blah.setText(getString(R.string.DESCRIPTION)+" Sometext");`

Comment: Yes sure, but as it's just static text i would like to set in xml and not programmatically.

Comment: joni: sometimes the 'sometext' needs to go in the middle of DESCRIPTION like "He was %s years old"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this can't be done.  You will have to do it in code:

```
textViewTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.DESCRIPTION) + ": ");
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted me, why?  I gave a perfectly acceptable solution (out of several possible solutions)

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar with [`Context.getString(id,args...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29). As an `Activity` inherits from `Context` you can just directly use it in code.

values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="DESCRIPTION">Hello %s</string>
```

Activity:

```
String result = getString(R.string.DESCRIPTION,"world");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, text attribute doesn't support this. But you can use formatting api for your goals. Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).